# Azerothcore connecting to internet via Docker

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-network, azerothcore

I have Azerothcore fresh installed using [install with Docker](http://www.azerothcore.org/wiki/Install-with-Docker) method.
I am able to connect over local network using `SET realmlist 192.168.1.242`

What is the best method to get docker or server to allow a friend to access over the internet? Do I have to follow a different install method? Wiki isn't very clear on this.

Answer (score 2):

Modify the `address` column of the `realmlist` table inside your `acore_auth` database and put there your public IP address.

Be aware that if you don't have a static IP address, then that value will frequently change. Also, you need to open the ports `3724` and `8085` of your router.

If you can't open your router ports, you can try using some VPN like [hamachi](https://www.vpn.net/) (in that case, your public address should be your hamachi one and your friends need to be in the same hamachi room of yours). This solves also the dynamic IP issue.